# Page works fine in Chrome,FF, completely left aligned in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm building a website from a template, I changed the border at the top of the page to it's on div so i can include some links...everything worked great, but when I checked IE suddenly the entire page is aligned to the left.

I've taken out the changes, including restoring the CSS from the template I originally started on...hasn't fixed it.  I'm completely confused, I have gone line by line through this and haven't been able to figure it out.

Page can be seen at http://test.crucialsolutions.net/

Thanks!!

Comment: Which version of IE you talking about? Page is centered for me in IE7 to IE10. Nevertheless you have no `DOCTYPE` in your page, so IE falls back to Quirksmode. Check http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a DocType should fix this issue...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and in your body and the class `main` you need to edit the margin like the following:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

You don't have a width in `class: main`. So add

```
width: 100%; /* according to your width size like width: 960px; */
```

Comment: Thanks!  Works now, I must have deleted it while change it up.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

use outer div with this css = style="width:1000px;margin:0px auto"

```
<div style="width: 1000px; margin: 0px auto;">
    <!--your code here-->
</div>
```

Comment: Please read the Stack Overflow FAQ and get used to proper code block formatting.

Answer (score 0):

you have no width properties on "header class" 
you have to give with:100% with float left .. 
and then inner div .. "header_resize" and other like it work well